# cast dynamic object in other type .net

Tags: .net, casting

.net 4 introduced dynamic objects where you can assign proprieties at a run time. I have dynamic object and need to cast it in to another type. Following is the code snippet

```
public class eObject : DynamicObject
{

        Dictionary<string, object> m_dictFields = new Dictionary<string, object>();

        private string m_strName;
        public string Name
        {
            get { return m_strName; }
            set { m_strName = value; }
        }

public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
 {
   if (m_dictFields.ContainsKey(binder.Name))
   {
    result = m_dictFields[binder.Name];
    return true;
  }
 else
 {
    return base.TryGetMember(binder, out result);
 }
}

public override bool TrySetMember(SetMemberBinder binder, object value)
 {
    if (!m_dictFields.ContainsKey(binder.Name))
      m_dictFields.Add(binder.Name, value);
    else
      m_dictFields[binder.Name] = value;
    return true;
 }
}



   // now I am assigning properties to my dynamic object as 

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        dynamic organization = new eObject();
        organization.Name = "Test Org Name";
        organization.ModifiedOn = DateTime.Now;
        organization.CreatedOn = DateTime.Now;
        organization.ModifiedBy = "Test Modified by";
        oganization.CreatedBy = "Test User";
        // this is what i have done
        eObject newOrg = organization as eObject;

        Console.WriteLine("Org Name: " +organization.Name);  // working            

        Console.WriteLine("Org Name: " +newOrg.Name);  // not working

    }
```

I am getting the newOrg object but the fields which I have added dynamically are not accessible to me.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When the compiler generates code for expression `organization.Name` it detects the type of the variable `organization` as being `dynamic`. Then it decides to postpone the 'binding'  process for execution time, because it does not know it the object behind the variable `organization` will have a `Name` or `ModifiedOn` properties. The methods `TryGetMember` and `TrySetMember` will be called during execution time whenever the dynamic object won't have the corresponding member. In this example `TryGetMember` and `TrySetMember` wont be called for property Name, because it is statically declared on `eObject`, but they will be called for the rest of member access you defined. 

When you cast the variable to `eObject` in newOrg, the compiler is back to static analisis, so it can see that newOrg references an object with a `Name` property, but no `ModifiedOn` property, so in particular `newOrg.Name` will work (I don't know why you say it doesn't), but `newOrg.ModifiedOn` won't pass the compiler verification, issuing the following error:

```
    'eObject' does not contain a definition for 'ModifiedBy' and no extension 
    method 'ModifiedBy' accepting a first argument of type 'eObject' could be 
    found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```